# Tagged Value Type - Collection of Structured Types in Enterprise Architect

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

Is it possible in Enterprise Architect to define as Tagged Value Type collection of some structured types?

For example if i need to extended Table's attributes with collection of N addresses (street, number, city) - hypothetical example:

```
Table: Person
Tagged Value: List of addresses -
                West Street, 1, New York
                South Street, 2, New York
                East Street, 3, New York
```

In general i want to simulate in EA what is known in PowerDesigner as Extended Composition of Extended Subobjects.

I followed suggestion to use RefGUIDList, what seems to be most close to my use case but failed as well:

1. I created Stereotype Address based on Class Metaclass and imported UML Profile containing this metatype to my data model:
   [image]
2. I defined Tagged Value Type List of Addresses as:
   [image]
3. I created a pair of Address objects and expected to be able to select between them when tagging table Person, but it did not work and no address showed up.
4. When removing filter for Types and Stereotypes from Tagged Value Type definition i was able to select Addresses between all objects in model:
   [image]

This behaviour is far from PowerDesigner's Extended Compositions functionality. In addition, i need to be able to create new Address right during editing Tagged Value List of Addresses and not before...

Comment: Search the help for RefGUID. I was about to write an answer but found it not to work as described (it did in the past, but EA is a sack of flees).

Comment: It's not clear what you mean exactly. Please illustrate with an example.

Comment: I added some use-case clarification and attempt to use RefGUIDList. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Adding a tagged values list is not the right way to add columns to a database table, if that's what you're trying to do. If it isn't, you shouldn't use a «table».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your List of Addresses definition is wrong. `Values` specifies the metatype, so it should be

```
Type=RefGUIDList;
Values=Class;
Stereotypes=Address;
```

When you've got it set up right, you can select the specified metaclass/stereotype using the ellipsis button. The dialog that opens has an Add New button, which allows you to create new elements of the proper type on the fly.

Comment: Thanks, that is almost everything that i wanted to proove. I guess it is possible to write my own plugin and show user instead of EA GUI my own more user-friendly form?